# grpc about 'a client-to-server stream RPC' but with an error of 'Exception iterating requests'

Tags: python, grpc

I made a demo about 'a client-to-server stream RPC', but when I run client, it appears an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/back_test_v2/gRPC/client/order_client.py", line 57, in <module>
    run_client()
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/back_test_v2/gRPC/client/order_client.py", line 41, in run_client
    response = stub.TransOrder(OrderRequest(orders = [SingleOrder(contract='asd',
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 1108, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 826, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
    details = "Exception iterating requests!"
    debug_error_string = "None"
>
```

and codes of server

```
class PlaceOrder(PlaceOrderServicer):
    def TransOrder(self, request_iterator, context):
        for request in request_iterator:
            print(f'contract is {request.contract}, begin_pos is {request.begin_pos}, end_pos is {request.end_pos}')

        return OrderReply()


def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor())
    add_PlaceOrderServicer_to_server(PlaceOrder(), server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50062')
    server.start()
```

codes of client:

```
def data():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        request = OrderRequest(orders=[SingleOrder(contract='asd',
                                                   begin_pos=i,
                                                   end_pos=i)])
        print("Visiting OrderRequest %s" % request.contract)
        yield request


def run_client():
    with grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50062') as channel:
        stub = PlaceOrderStub(channel)

        data1 = data()
        response = stub.TransOrder(data1)
```

protos

```
service PlaceOrder {
  rpc TransOrder (stream OrderRequest) returns (OrderReply) {}
}

//报单
message SingleOrder {
  string contract = 1;
  int32 begin_pos = 2;
  int32 end_pos = 3;
}
//输出参数
message OrderRequest {
  repeated SingleOrder orders = 1;
}
//输出参数
// 不需要返回消息
message OrderReply {
}
```

I make it as easy as possible, but I still can't figure out what is the problem. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The `Exception iterating requests!` error message means there is an Exception raised in the request iterator. I would recommend to add a try-catch clause in the client-side `def data()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe this post might be bit late, But at least for those who might wonder over her looking for a resolution, hope below solves your issue, for me it did!!

The non blocking stub method is looking for an iterator, but the yield command or the data() method returns a Generator object which might be reason your getting that error, try passing the generator's iterator attribute - that solved the issue for me.

The code snippet-

```
def data():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        request = OrderRequest(orders=[SingleOrder(contract='asd',
                                                   begin_pos=i,
                                                   end_pos=i)])
        print("Visiting OrderRequest %s" % request.contract)
        yield request


def run_client():
    with grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50062') as channel:
        stub = PlaceOrderStub(channel)

        data1 = data()
        #Below change should resolve the issue
        response = stub.TransOrder(data1.__iter()__)
```